# Calculating dynamic value from request body parameters in Paw

Tags: paw-app

I have methods in my API that have so be signed with hash of request parameters. Let's say I have three params in my request: 'first', 'second' and 'variable', which is set from environment variable. I need to add fourth parameter 'hash', which is equal to MD5([first][second][variable]):

[image]

test_var equals to 'test_variable'

To do this I calculate MD5 with Request Parsed Body params, which are read from current request. I get warnings that these params cannot be used because of self-dependency, and that request has an empty body, but MD5 is actually calculated correctly: MD5(firstParamsecondParamtest_variable) = 09f8669986f4152487da543e12e1e393

[image]

But, when I send this request hash value changes somehow, and is no longer correct:

first=firstParam&second=secondParam&variable=test_variable&hash=d3a0cc12d51633f07820b9d5ff167126

What's wrong?

Comment: Link to request in Pawprint: https://paw.pt/aRniaIOC

Comment: Sorry for late answer @Spail... I've found a workaround for you as ther is no way currently to achieve this otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been fixed in newer versions of Paw. You can simply do like suggested in the question. Right-click and pick Request > Request Parsed Body.

[image: Set a reference to another part of the request body in Paw]

Add all the references you need, and you'll have the wanted hash:

[image: Referencing a hash in a request in Paw]

You now have the MD5 of the three first params concatenated (no error reported).

Comment: I have a similar porblem like above .But in my request I have to hash all the key and body like hash = MD5(key1=value1key2=value2...secretKey) , I want to write it in js code ,but I cannot get the other request params in body. Are you have any idea about my problem ? Thank you

Comment: Why can't you compose your MD5 hash in the Paw UI? In the example I've show in the answer, I've been able to concatenate multiple strings together.